# How to display about 80 fields on an asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to retrieve a single row of data from sqlserver and display it on an asp.net page. The problem is that the row has about 80 fields. Is there a server control which could handle it? I believe repeator and datalist controls work on multiple rows of data. Also in order to prevent a very long page requiring too much of scrolling, I have to display as three columns. A sample is given below

```
First Name: Value     Last Name: Value   MI: Value
Address1:   Value      Address2: Value    City: Value
SSN:        Value      DOB: Value        Phone: Value
..........More Data.................
....................................
```

I could manually create a label/label pair to display each field name and the corresponding field value. I am wondering whether there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: I think that's probably a good way to do it. you can programatically insert the lables by getting the column name and then the cell data, that's probably how I'd do it

Comment: As you already know that there is only one row, could you just simply use ***Label*** or ***Literal*** controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`DataList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) control with [`RepeatLayout.Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatlayout.aspx). Then set the [`RepeatColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) property to the number of columns you want to show.

[**How to: Specify Horizontal or Vertical Layout in DataList Web Server Controls**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79k821wc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did, and worked nicely

Answer (score 1):

To display a single row with mutltiple fields use [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx) control.

Comment: Not good to display a row of 80 fields imho.

Comment: Details view is good, but limits how much control you have over style.